# Is my graphics card done for?

Tags: graphics-card

A few days ago as I was playing some games my computer suddenly crashed and screen went black and it started smelling like something was burned. I opened my pc and arrived at the conclusion that its because of my gpu since it smelled burned and everything else was working just fine without it. I haven't tried putting it back on the motherboard because I am afraid that it might ruin the system which thankfully it didn't happen before.

I've opened it to an extent but did not see anything burned but I didn't reach to the core since I couldn't get the cooling parts off.

So I want to ask if there's any way that I can check if it still works to eliminate the slight possibility of it still being alive. Any other ideas on the matter would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Uh-oh. You let the magic smoke out.

But, seriously, if you smelled burnt rosin, then a component failed to a dead short on that graphics card. Putting it back in invites another failure of other components. Your PC's power supply and motherboard *might* withstand it; or might not.

Even if I know what make and model you had, I would not risk it unless I could afford to replace the PC. But, I don't need to know that in this case; toast is toast.

Comment: We don’t actually need information on the graphics card, magic smoke, is magic smoke.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: If the answer provides useful information, you can click on the up arrowhead to the left to the top of the answer. If the answer also is the best and solves the issue, you can also also click on the checkmark just below the arrowheads. This shows others how to solve the same problem if they're looking for a solution here.